# Marionette: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm studying Backbone with Marionette and Rails as backend, using screencast and I got stuck with this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FooterApp is not defined
```

My **app.js.coffee** code:

```
@Demo = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

    App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application

    App.addRegions
        headerRegion: "#header-region"
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
        footerRegion: "#footer-region"

    App.addInitializer ->
        App.module("FooterApp").start()
        #App.execute "footer:show"

    App.on "initialize:after", ->
        if Backbone.history
            Backbone.history.start()

    App
```

**footer_app.js.coffee**

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp", (FooterApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

    API = 
        showFooter: ->
            FooterApp.Show.Controller.showFooter()

    FooterApp.on "start", ->
        API.showFooter()
```

and **show_controller.js.coffee**

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    Show.Controller = 

        showFooter: ->
            console.log 'test'
```

I spent a lot of time figuring out what is wrong but still have no clue..

Answer (score 1):

In your code you haven't initialized your controller at any point, it should read a bit more like this

```
API = 
    showFooter: ->
        new FooterApp.Show.Controller
```

and then in your Footer controller you can have an initialize function that would show it

```
initialize: ->
    console.log 'test'
```